# Attempting to get the top 50 songs in each country from Spotify's API along with their relevant track information

Tags: r, api, spotify

The resulting data frame contains no data

This is my current code:

```
# Function to retrieve top tracks from Spotify API
get_top_tracks <- function(access_token, country) {
  charts_url <- "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/charts"
  charts_params <- list(
    limit = 50,
    offset = 0,
    country = country
  )
  charts_header <- add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", access_token))
  charts_response <- GET(charts_url, query = charts_params, charts_header)
  top_tracks <- content(charts_response)$tracks$items
  return(top_tracks)
}

# Spotify API access token
access_token <- get_access_token(client_id, client_secret)

# List of countries
countries <- c("US", "GB", "DE", "FR", "AU")  # Add more countries as desired

# Create an empty dataframe to store the top tracks
top_tracks_data <- data.frame()

# Loop through each country
for (country in countries) {
  # Get top tracks from Spotify API
  top_tracks <- get_top_tracks(access_token, country)
  
  # Extract relevant information from the top tracks
  track_ids <- sapply(top_tracks, function(track) track$id)
  track_names <- sapply(top_tracks, function(track) track$name)
  artists <- sapply(top_tracks, function(track) track$artists[[1]]$name)
  popularity <- sapply(top_tracks, function(track) track$popularity)
  
  # Create a data frame with the extracted information
  country_data <- data.frame(
    Country = country,
    Track_ID = track_ids,
    Track_Name = track_names,
    Artist = artists,
    Popularity = popularity,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  
  # Add the country data to the combined dataframe
  top_tracks_data <- bind_rows(top_tracks_data, country_data)
}

# Print the top tracks data
print(top_tracks_data)
```

Is the problem with the API? I assume not and I am just pulling the data incorrectly but where is my error? Is there a simpler way to go about this or some dataset that exists that I have just not found. Thank you for any help

Comment: Have you tried printing `top_tracks` in the for loop? It looks like it might turn out being `NULL`. Typically API's don't return data.frames where you can use the `$` operator